# What's the correct way of waiting for detached threads to finish?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Look at this sample code:

```
void OutputElement(int e, int delay)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100 * delay));
    cout << e << '\n';
}

void SleepSort(int v[], uint n)
{
    for (uint i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        thread t(OutputElement, v[i], v[i]);
        t.detach();
    }
}
```

It starts `n` new threads and each one sleeps for some time before outputting a value and finishing. What's the correct/best/recommended way of waiting for all threads to finish in this case? I know how to work around this but I want to know what's the recommended multithreading tool/design that I should use in this situation (e.g. `condition_variable`, `mutex` etc...)?

Comment: Just don't `detach()` your `thread`s.  Then you can `join()` them properly.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I have `n` `std::thread` objects, start them all and then call `join()` on them all?

Comment: Yes, just like in @KerrekSB's answer.  Actually, you should almost never `detach()` a `thread`.

Comment: Almost. So when **should** I?

Comment: Don't wait for them to finish.  If there are no bad consequences in having them forcibly terminated at any stage, just let the OS terminate them at process termination.

Comment: @MartinJames Nothing would crash or break in this case but I **would** like my sort to finish sorting.

Comment: @NPS For every C++ feature, there is probably a use case where there exists a good reason to use it.  That's why I refrain from saying things like “never use X”.  But to be honest, I don't know an example where I would use `std::thread::detach` myself and feel good with it.  Maybe if you want true “fire and forget” semantics and your thread doesn't mind being killed at program termination.  But it is hard to see when this would offer a real advantage over a RAII-style `join()` guard at global scope.

Comment: @5gon12eder no.  You should never not-detach a thread unless there is an overriding reason to do so.

Comment: 30 years I have been telling developers to NOT wait for thread termination unless absolutely necessary.  Only the OS can stop threads in any state. User code cannot stop a thread running on another core than the one requesting process termination.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, if you don't take it from me, you might be interested to read what Stroustrup says about it in *The C++ Programming Language* (4th edition).  I guess you can debate it, but at least, it's nothing that I have made up in my mind.

Comment: He's pretty clueless re. multithreading, TBH.   On any non-trivial OS, not waiting for thread termination is hugely preferable to making a blocking join() call unless there are overriding circumstances, (such as flushing files and/or DB connections).

Comment: @NPS But why do want to detach the thread?

Comment: @Jagannath Honestly? I'm not sure... :P

Answer (score 10):

And now for the slightly dissenting answer.  And I do mean *slightly* because I mostly agree with the other answer and the comments that say "don't detach, instead join."

First imagine that there is no `join()`.  And that you have to communicate among your threads with a `mutex` and `condition_variable`.  This really isn't that hard nor complicated.  And it allows an arbitrarily rich communication, which can be anything you want, as long as it is only communicated while the mutex is locked.

Now a very common idiom for such communication would simply be a state that says "I'm done".  Child threads would set it, and the parent thread would wait on the condition_variable until the child said "I'm done."  This idiom would in fact be so common as to deserve a convenience function that encapsulated the `mutex`, `condition_variable` and state.

`join()` is precisely this convenience function.

But imho one has to be careful.  When one says:  "Never `detach`, always `join`," that could be interpreted as:  Never make your thread communication more complicated than "I'm done."

For a more complex interaction between parent thread and child thread, consider the case where a parent thread launches several child threads to go out and independently search for the solution to a problem.  When the problem is first found by any thread, that gets communicated to the parent, and the parent can then take that solution, and tell all the other threads that they don't need to search any more.

For example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void OneSearch(int id, std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> mut,
                   std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cv,
                   int& state, int& solution)
{
    std::random_device seed;
//     std::mt19937_64 eng{seed()};
    std::mt19937_64 eng{static_cast<unsigned>(id)};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 100000000);
    int test = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        {
            ++test;
            if (dist(eng) == 999)
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*mut);
                if (state == -1)
                {
                    state = id;
                    solution = test;
                    cv->notify_one();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*mut);
        if (state != -1)
            return;
    }
}

auto findSolution(int n)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    auto mut = std::make_shared<std::mutex>();
    auto cv = std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>();
    int state = -1;
    int solution = -1;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*mut);
    for (uint i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(OneSearch, i, mut, cv,
                          std::ref(state), std::ref(solution)));
    while (state == -1)
        cv->wait(lk);
    lk.unlock();
    for (auto& t : threads)
        t.join();
    return std::make_pair(state, solution);
}

int
main()
{
    auto p = findSolution(5);
    std::cout << '{' << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}\n";
}
```

Above I've created a "dummy problem" where a thread searches for how many times it needs to query a URNG until it comes up with the number 999.  The parent thread puts 5 child threads to work on it.  The child threads work for awhile, and then every once in a while, look up and see if any other thread has found the solution yet.  If so, they quit, else they keep working.  The main thread waits until solution is found, and then **joins** with all the child threads.

For me, using the bash time facility, this outputs:

```
$ time a.out
{3, 30235588}

real    0m4.884s
user    0m16.792s
sys 0m0.017s
```

But what if instead of joining with all the threads, it detached those threads that had not yet found a solution.  This might look like:

```
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (i == state)
            threads[i].join();
        else
            threads[i].detach();
    }
```

(in place of the `t.join()` loop from above).  For me this now runs in 1.8 seconds, instead of the 4.9 seconds above.  I.e. the child threads are not checking with each other that often, and so main just detaches the working threads and lets the OS bring them down.  This is safe for this example because the child threads own everything they are touching.  Nothing gets destructed out from under them.

One final iteration can be realized by noticing that even the thread that finds the solution doesn't need to be joined with.  *All* of the threads could be detached.  The code is actually much simpler:

```
auto findSolution(int n)
{
    auto mut = std::make_shared<std::mutex>();
    auto cv = std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>();
    int state = -1;
    int solution = -1;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*mut);
    for (uint i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
        std::thread(OneSearch, i, mut, cv,
                          std::ref(state), std::ref(solution)).detach();
    while (state == -1)
        cv->wait(lk);
    return std::make_pair(state, solution);
}
```

And the performance remains at about 1.8 seconds.

There is still (sort of) an effective join with the solution-finding thread here.  But it is accomplished with the `condition_variable::wait` instead of with `join`.

`thread::join()` is a convenience function for the very common idiom that your parent/child thread communication protocol is simply "I'm done."  Prefer `thread::join()` in this common case as it is easier to read, and easier to write.

However don't unnecessarily constrain yourself to such a simple parent/child communication protocol.  And don't be afraid to build your own richer protocol when the task at hand needs it.  And in this case, `thread::detach()` will often make more sense.  `thread::detach()` doesn't necessarily imply a fire-and-forget thread.  It can simply mean that your communication protocol is more complex than "I'm done."

Comment: Great answer but isn't the win by `detach()`ing the threads here at least partially gained by the fact that in your example `main` returns immediately?  If this is inside a more complex program, we'd still keep spinning threads around for a short while. I think the biggest win here would be to communicate via an atomic flag so to avoid the need for locking.  Then, we can also poll the flag more frequently.  If simplicity is the goal, a `std::packaged_task` might be useful.

Comment: @5gon12eder:  The point of this example is to illustrate that legitimate cases exist for `detach` beyond fire-and-forget, and that `join` is just a convenience function encapsulating a mutex and condition_variable. There are always going to be tradeoffs between mutexes, atomics, and polling frequencies, and there is no solution that is optimal for all use cases.  This answer is about enlarging your toolbox to include `detach` combined with alternative communication via `mutex` and `condition_variable`.  Certainly atomics and `packaged_task` ought to be in your toolbox too.

Answer (score 5):

Don't detach, but instead *join*:

```
std::vector<std::thread> ts;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    ts.emplace_back(OutputElement, v[i], v[i]);

for (auto & t : threads)
    t.join();
```

Comment: why? join is blocking

Comment: @user3085931: Yes. See this in the context of the question, which asks for a way to "wait", i.e. block.